# call home and delete 'caller' lines of code (Keep track of pages that use code)

Tags: php, email

I created a php widget (one file) for free download, and I'd like to see it in action on the sites where it is implemented.

Is there any way to add a couple of lines, preferably packed, that will send me a mail with the host page url - and than remove this lines of code?

I'm not a php expert so it's all on guessings for now.

p.s.
Is that legal?..

- One file (with php, html, jquery, css. inside)
- Add lines to 'call home', **obfuscated** to prevent people bombard my email:)
- Once script runs for first time - send mail - delete lines of 'call home' code.

Comment: `mail` to send a mail, `file_get_contents` to read a file (like a PHP file!) into a string, `file_put_contents` to write a string into a file. Look them up in the PHP manual and you will have your few lines of code.

Comment: but that won't keep anyone from deleting these lines beforehand.

Comment: Attempting to write code to keep someone from deleting code in that same text file is a bit futile.

Comment: what is 'futile' ? I agree, I'm not concerned about a couple of people that will delete an obfuscated part of code. I think lots won't. The php file has html, jquery, xml, php lines of code, and how to tell to delete exactly Ex: from line nN to line Nn all the code?

Comment: @Dan All of this won't be obfuscated. roXon your email will be visible, this is (IMO) a bad solution. frdjad idea of a setup script is better.

Comment: Oh and I don't know if that's legal, but that is not very ethical to track people that way (even though your intentions are not bad). Leaving the option in the setup to "notify" you that your code is being used is good, but maybe not everyone will. That's not really related, but you can also install a download counter on your website, to know how many people have used your script.

Comment: I already have a download counter and even a 'leave a comment or a thanks'. But people seem too busy to say 'thanks'... Yes, it's all self-satisfaction-related thing, the most sensitive part of our job. Where enough people do not understand what make us happy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deleting lines from the source file you would create a `Setup` script to deploy the script and tell the user that you're tracking the installation so this will be legal.

Comment: You can also implement the `Setup` approach by using an `All in one` script (one file): if (file_exists(`.installed`) { `WIDGET CODE` } else { `SEND AN EMAIL AND CREATE .installed FILE` }

Comment: You don't tell the user. You _ask_ them.